# How to display a document.write in a particular tag by id

Tags: javascript

How can I document.write in a particular tag?

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json){
document.write("", json.ip);}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

I want it to be inside

```
<input name="ip" value="" type="text">
```

Comment: document.getElementById('idtaghere')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite your function so that you assign the result of your JSON.ip to the value of the input element. Try something like this:

```
function getIP(json){
   document.getElementById('input_id').value = json.ip;
}
```